# python web-scraping ' Connection broken'

Tags: python, web-scraping

Yap

When I crawler some website, the code return an error

Error code：

```
requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(10054, 'The remote host has forcibly closed an existing connection', None, 10054, None)", ConnectionResetError(10054, '
The remote host has forcibly closed an existing connection', None, 10054, None))
```

What should I do?

This never happened to me before.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using header parameter when calling request.get() ?? The website could be detecting a bot and denying the connection, with header it doesn0t anymore. If you haven't try, try it: insert this into the request.get(header={User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0}) and the other parameters that u already have!

Comment: This is my header already exist


`headers = { 
"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36"
 }`

Comment: Alright i don't know then. but it is not from that. u can remove what i told u to add then